# Changing all the values of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I multiply all of the values in a dictionary by a set number?

```
dictionary = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
number = 2
```

I want to multiply all of the values in `dictionary` by `number` so that a second dictionary is created called `dictionary2`

The dictionary created should look something like this:

```
dictionary2 = {'one': 2, 'two': 4 'three': 6}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a dictionary comprehension

```
>>> dictionary = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
>>> number = 2
>>> {key:value*number for key,value in dictionary.items()}
{'one': 2, 'three': 6, 'two': 4}
```

(Note that the order is not the same as dictionaries are inherently unordered)

As a statement

```
dictionary2 = {key:value*number for key,value in dictionary.items()}
```

If you want a trivial version you can use a for loop

```
dictionary = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
number = 2
dictionary2 = {}

for i in dictionary:
    dictionary2[i] = dictionary[i]*number

print(dictionary2)
```